# Inkscape to TikZ math text misalignment

Tags: tikz-pgf, text, inkscape

How do I produce correct TikZ pictures from Inkscape, where the Math text is correctly aligned?
Right now my image in InkScape looks like this:
[image: Setup in TikZ]
I have connected all text to its appropriate shape. All text is setup as being centered. However, when I render this in Overleaf, it gets to look like this:
[image: Overleaf/LaTeX render]
Which is clearly not my intention. Am I doing something wrong, or isn't there a good mapping from Inkscape to LaTeX natively?

Comment: I think drawing such diagrams directly is quicker than using Inkscape

Comment: Maybe yes, already burnt too much time on this issue, but realisticly, this should work I would say. Seeing the works of others..

Comment: Most likely you have set somewhere some keys that trigger `align=left,text width=...` without being aware of it. I agree with @JouleV that you will be much better off if you draw this with some code and not with some click-click-click tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this quick code is close to what you want

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\inw}{inw}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\begin{scope}
    \clip (0,0) circle (2);
    \fill[gray!30] (3,0) circle (2);
\end{scope}
\draw[very thick] (0,0) node {$A$} circle (2) (3,0) node {$B$} circle (2);
\draw (1.5,0) -- (1.5,-2) node[below] {$A\cap B$};
\draw (-3,-3) rectangle (6,3);
\path (5.5,2.5) node[below left] {$V$};
\draw (0,2) -- ++ (0,1.5) node[above] {$\overline{A}$};
\draw (-1,.5) -- ++ (-2.5,0) node[left] {$\inw(A)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Only with a `\clip`, one can save a lot of time (I'm sure clicking the mouse is really time consuming).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to JouleV's answer but with different means to draw the circles (they are nodes here) and to shade the intersection.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\inw}{inw}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\tikzset{use path/.code=\pgfsetpath#1} % learned from Kpym
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[thick,circle,draw,inner sep=1em,save path=\pathA] (A) at (-0.5,0) {$A$};
 \node[thick,circle,draw,inner sep=1em,save path=\pathB] (B) at (0.5,0) {$B$};
 \begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \clip[use path=\pathA];
  \fill[gray!30,use path=\pathB];
 \end{scope}
 \draw ([xshift=-2em,yshift=-1.5em]current bounding box.south west)
  rectangle ([xshift=2em,yshift=1.5em]current bounding box.north east);
 \draw (0,0) -- (0,-2em) node[below] {$A \cap B$};
 \draw ([xshift=-1ex,yshift=1ex]A.center) -- ++ (-1.5,0) node[left]{$\inw(A)$};
 \draw (A.north) -- ++ (0,2em) node[above]{$\overline{A}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of having a `\path[clip]`, I think Ti*k*Z should have an `\path[unfill]` and `\path[undraw]`. Using `clip` for a complicated Venn requires a huge effort.

Comment: @JouleV In principle these things exist. There is a `reverseclip` style around and an `even odd clip`, which do what I think you are suggesting. If you are saying that these should be part of the automatically loaded things, I fully agree, and I would also want to add `use path` to the list.